# Configure eclipse debugger to filter out library methods I didn't write when navigating the stack?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm using a number of frameworks, boot, hibernate, etc, in our code, including enhancing and generating code.  When I call what looks like a simple method of code it will go through CglibAoPProxy and similar methods before to call the method I want.  This means if I want to look into the next piece of my code I need to either walk through 5 lays of stack trace for code I presume is functional (and thus don't care to trace it's logic) to get to the next method of code I personally wrote, or add breakpoints and where I want to break, hit run, and then remove the breakpoint after.

What would be nice is if there was an easy way to tell the debugger that I only want to look at my code.  If I step into a method implemented by some library just keep running until it hits the next line of code that is part of a library I wrote.  Is there an easy way to configure the debugger to do this?  to only care about code I personally wrote when stepping into something?

Likewise, when I want to move back up the stack trace, to look at an earlier phase state, it's very difficult.  With so many levels of methods from libraries it's hard to find the ones that contain code I personally wrote.  Is there a way to highlight only your methods (say methods from the current working set) or something similar in the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Step filters](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-usestepfilters.htm) may help.

1. Open Eclipse preferences. For example, on Windows, use the menu item *Windows>Preferences*.
2. Navigate to *Java>Debug>Step Filtering*.
3. Turn on the checkbox *Use Step Filtering*.
4. In the checkbox list titled *Defined step filters*, turn on checkboxes of package hierarchies you'd like to skip. Use the buttons alongside to add additional filters.

All that said, I hadn't used step filtering until your question led me to look into it. Not yet sure how I personally feel about skipping code while debugging. But that last item in the default filter list -- `java.lang.ClassLoader` -- looks very helpful.

Comment: I figured skipping code is fine so long as I can toggle the feature on and off.  If I can't see something obvious I can always allow do a second more through debug process.  This seems like it's what I want!  Though, it would be nice to have a way to make moving up the stack trace easier as well; something to highlight code I personally wrote as separate from library code for instance. Then I would have everything I wanted.

Comment: I've had step filtering on all day, with `java.lang.ClassLoader` filtered out. No problems observed. Stepping into ClassLoader has been annoying me for a long time. Thank you for asking this question. Sorry, I don't see a way to filter the stack trace.